# Filter a dataframe based on today's date and other condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Date                        Status                    Price
2019-10-07 10:24:51         Yes                       20
2019-10-07 10:27:56         No                        50
2020-01-13 12:27:54         No                        40
2020-01-13 10:27:50         Yes                       80
2020-01-13 12:28:52         Yes                       45
```

From the above data, I would like to filter based on today's date in terms of day  and Status == Yes.

Note: I have to run this daily based on day of today's date time.

Expected Output:

```
Date                        Status                    Price
2020-01-13 10:27:50         Yes                       80
2020-01-13 12:28:52         Yes                       45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with compare dates created by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with today `date`s and chain mask by compare `Yes` values:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df[df['Date'].dt.date.eq(pd.to_datetime('now').date()) & df['Status'].eq('Yes')]

#in last versions of pandas is possible compare dates with today datime
df = df[df['Date'].dt.date.eq(pd.to_datetime('now')) & df['Status'].eq('Yes')]
print (df)
                 Date Status  Price
3 2020-01-13 10:27:50    Yes     80
4 2020-01-13 12:28:52    Yes     45
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.to_datetime('now'))
2020-01-13 07:42:02.592142

print (pd.to_datetime('now').date())
2020-01-13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) if needed convert to datetime first
df[df['Date'].dt.date.eq(pd.to_datetime('today')) & df['Status'].eq('Yes')]
```

---

```
                 Date Status  Price
3 2020-01-13 10:27:50    Yes     80
4 2020-01-13 12:28:52    Yes     45
```